# InDesign CS6 - Content conveyor: placing collected objects (links) at their original positions

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, optimization, workflow

With the intent of easily updating elements across several pages I am using the content collector tool to place linked objects.

I am finding it unpractical to precisely position several collected elements on new pages at their original coordinates.

**Question 1**:
Is there a way to place several collected elements and maintain their original positions?

**Question 2**:
Are there any other ways of duplicating page contents while retaining links to their respective InDesign internal source objects?

Note: I don't wish to use any external links in this case, just internally linked objects, like one would use symbols in Illustrator.

Comment: So far the simplest solution seems to be positioning linked elements manually the first time and then duplicate the resulting page. Not a very flexible workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing a bit more about the workflow you're attempting, I would say the simplest way to do this with the content conveyor would be to group the objects first, the use the content conveyor to collect and place the group. If necessary, include a null object, such as an empty frame, at one corner of the page, so that you can click on that corner of the target page to place the group.

Grouped objects remember their positions within the group, so that should get you where you need to be.

Perhaps an even simpler workflow would be to cut all your objects from your initial layout and paste them onto a special Master Page, derived from your A-Master. Drag the special Master Page icon in the Pages Panel onto the icon for any page where you want them to appear. You can override (`Ctl/Cmd-Shift-Click`) and delete individual objects that you don't need on a given page.

When you update the objects on the master page, they automatically update on all the pages where they appear.